# carousel navigation each function

Tags: jquery, carousel, owl-carousel

I've got a page using multiple carousel (Owl carousel), each of them have a navigation such as prev/next.
Some of them have not enough items to be consider as a carousel so i want to disabled the navigation for this one.
The structure look :

```
<div class="videos-wrap">
<div class="owlnav owlnav1"><div class="owl-prev" style="">&lt;</div><div class="owl-next" style="">&gt;</div></div>
    <div class="video-carousel"></div>
    <div class="video-carousel"></div>
    <div class="video-carousel"></div>
</div>

<div class="videos-wrap">
<div class="owlnav owlnav1"><div class="owl-prev" style="">&lt;</div><div class="owl-next" style="">&gt;</div></div>
    <div class="video-carousel"></div>
</div>
```

...

I've try to do several things such as

```
$(".videos-wrap").each(function() {
var n = $( ".video-carousel" ).length;  
if (n < 3) {
    $('this .owlnav').css('display', 'none');
}
```

});

But not working

AnY ideas ?

Thxs for your help

Comment: Please be more spesific about your problem. What does "not working?" means? What are you trying to do with that js code and what are you getting? Unexpected result? Error?

Comment: You could check if it'll work if you change it to e.g.  `$(this).find('.owlnav').css('display', 'none');` instead

Comment: Great idea, but the effect is that all navigation are disabled even if i've more than 3 items in a slider. maybe each is not the correct function to do that 'm going to understand the documentation instead of my awful english :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track. Try this:

```
$(".videos-wrap").each(function() {
    var n = $(this).find(".video-carousel").length;
    if (n < 3) {
        $('.owlnav', this).css('display', 'none');
    }
});
```

The changes simply find the children of the current `.videos-wrap` with class `.video-carousel`. Then I did a little change to the selector that changes the display.

See it live: http://jsfiddle.net/g6d39b04/

Comment: Nearly but this one hide all carousel that don't have more than 3 slide (I just want to disable the navigation).
Thxs it's gonna be a source of inspiration

Comment: Then it is a matter of changing the selector to the actual one you want to hide. What is the class for the navigation?

Comment: the navigation is in .owlnav, your code if i understanded it as well should worked but disabled the all carousel not the navigation

Comment: $('.owlnav', this).css('display', 'none'); work thanks for your help